# How to smoothen graphs with python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, matplotlib, normalization

I am trying to smoothen this plot. But I was unable to do it. Tried to interpolate using splrep but its not working. Any help would be highly appreciated. The graph has been plotted by using Dataframe columns of Current, voltage and Operating hours.
[image]

[image]

```python
df2=data[:2000]
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(df2['Op_Hours_Fcpm'],df2['Current'],'r')
plt.xlabel('Operating hours')
plt.title('Current Fluctuations')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(df2['Op_Hours_Fcpm'],df2['Voltage'],'y')
plt.xlabel('Operating hours')
plt.title('Voltage Fluctuations')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I did try by another way as well:

```python
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_int, current_int, lw = 5, alpha = 0.30, label = 'current')
ax.plot(x_int, voltage_int, lw = 5, alpha = 0.30, label = 'voltage')

ax.set_xlabel('ripples')
ax.set_ylabel('hrs')
# Set the correct xticks
ax.set_xticks(x_map)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
fig.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.7, 0.3), loc='upper left', ncol=1)
fig.show()
```

This has given this output [image]

Comment: Please share your code that you used to create these graphs

Comment: Hi@Maaddy,, I am updating my question with the code snippet and data structure..

Comment: What is your desired output ? the second graph looks "smooth" to me. What exactly do you mean by "smooth" ?

Comment: Hi Maaddy, my main purpose is to make the first graph ' subplots' smooth as the second one.

Comment: I want to modify my first script, can you aid any help? My main purpose is to plot current and voltage in the same or a separate plot and analyse their transient nature. But I want a smooth curve instead of line.

Comment: Thanks for your very useful explanation Maaddy.It makes sense. I can provide you the data via email,,If you can provide me one..

Comment: Actually it is @Ben who answered not me :)

Comment: O, yes.I am so sorry,Thanks for correcting me Maady Thanks@ Ben. .. So, Ben would you like to have a look at my original data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide the original data, I tried to recreate some of the points from the image using

```
import pandas
print(pandas.__version__)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0.5, 0.5, 1,   1, 2,    2,  2 , 3]
y = [0,   600, 0, 600, 0, 1000, 600, 0]
plt.plot(x,y,'r');
plt.xlabel('Operating hours')
plt.title('Current Fluctuations');
plt.savefig('original.png');
```

which yields

[image: original]

The issue with the first subplot is that some of the times contain multiple values, including both "zero" and non-zero values. This can be more easily seen as a scatter plot

```
plt.scatter(x, y);
plt.xlabel('Operating hours')
plt.title('Current Fluctuations');
plt.savefig('scatter.png')
```

[image: scatter]

This visualization issue points to a problem with the underlying data.

One option would be to discard data that is zero and only keep non-zero data points.